# Python os function not working as intended?

Tags: python

Am I missing something here, I am attempting to make a directory then change CWD into that directory, however it keeps throwing an error saying "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:". This only happens if I first remove the directory and start with no directory there, once its created the first time it works fine.
If I run the code twice it works, first time I get the error.

```
import os


def func_name_here():
    os.popen('mkdir -p /tmp/tun')
    os.chdir(r'/tmp/tun')


func_name_here()
```

This gives me...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    func_name_here()
  File "test.py", line 6, in func_name_here
    os.chdir(r'/tmp/tun')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tun'
```

Comment: try using os.mkdir() instead of popen

Comment: That worked in this scenario. However I have a further development, if I want to create a directory with os.mkdir() that has a parent it doesn't work, how do I do the equivalent with os.mkdir() to mkdir -p? As if I change the above code to create /tmp/tun/test instead it fails with the same error

Comment: Nvm figured it out lol os.makedirs()

Comment: os.makedirs() method in Python is used to create a directory recursively. That means while making leaf directory if any intermediate-level directory is missing, os.makedirs() method will create them all.

Comment: Thanks. I did initially try os.mkdir() but because it did not work recursively I switched to popen in a hope to get it working (without checking for the recursive thing), for what ever reason popen doesn't work, however it works now with os.makedirs()

Comment: Otherwise you could have also added a forward slash at the end of your original code to make it run`os.chdir(r'/tmp/tun/')`. I suggest also to take a look at the `tempfile` library if you want to create non persistent temporary directories
 `

Comment: @f-starace I tried that with no luck, I think the issue is with popen not creating the directory the first time for some reason, and thanks, I am already using mkstemp, I just put this code together to demonstrate the initial error I was getting at a breakpoint.

Comment: @Z.Davey weird. I had the same issue while trying your code. I looked at the tmp folder and noticed that effectively tun was created. But adding the final `/` after `tun` in `os.chdir(r'tmp/tun/')` solved it for me

Comment: @f-starace Wait do you mean you was trying the code I put, using `os.popen()` ? I just tried it again using that and put the forward slash in `os.chdir()` and still no luck. `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tun/'` However tun was created. Very confusing, run it a second time it works just fine. However changing `os.popen()` to `os.mkdir()` it works fine first try (without the / on the end of chdir too). Does anyone know why?

Comment: @Z.Davey my first assumption was that ‘os.popen()’ run “asynchronously” thus next loc run without awaiting for the directory to be created. By reading the docs it seems ‘popen()’ returns a file descriptor of an open file object connected to the pipe, thus it might be cause the file is created and not stored yet at the first run. But I’m curious as well to learn more